# How to make console JavaScript wait for reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

This will print the same name multiple time, rather than waiting for the page reload. How can I make sure the new value of 'name' gets printed after refresh?

```
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i += 1) {
    document.querySelector("img[id='buttonReload']").click();
    setTimeout(window.location.reload, 1000);
    m = document.querySelector("a[id='name']").innerText;
    console.log(m);
}
```

Comment: The code to print the value should be in the page's `onload` function.

Comment: Thanks - this is being run from console. How do I do that ther?

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: `setTimeout()` returns immediately, it doesn't wait for the timeout to complete.